# Find primitive elements of a splitting field

Tags: group-theory, galois-theory

> Find all primitive elements from a splitting field of polynomial $x^3 - 5 = 0 $ over a field $Q$ and describe its Galois group.

I found splitting field, but how to find which elements in that field is primitive?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_element_theorem#Constructive_results and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_element_theorem#Example.

Comment: Are you sure that you need to find ALL primitive elements? This is a hard task...

Comment: my task say that I have to find all, but if I understand how primitive elements work, I have to find only one, and all other can be found as $a^p$
@lhf, thank you for your answer, it helped me, but I cannot understand how they create system of linear equation when they trying to calculate one element via another

Comment: It seems to me that $Q$ does not denote the field of rational numbers... Or does it? What is $p$ then?

Answer (score 3):

It’s not so hard, once you’ve described the splitting field and its Galois group over the rational field $\Bbb Q$. There’s the full splitting field $K$, and four intermediate fields $k_i$, where $1\le i\le 4$. Any element of $K$ not in any of the fields $k_i$ will be a primitive element. You do the rest.